# If $a$, $b$, $c$ are three positive integers such that $a^3+b^3=c^3$ then one of the integer is divisible by $7$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

Let on contrary that none of the $a$, $b$, $c$ is divisible by $7$. Then either $a^3\equiv  b^3\pmod{7}$ or $b^3\equiv  c^3\pmod{7}$ or $c^3\equiv  a^3\pmod{7}$.
Now how to go further?

Comment: Hint: Siince $x^6\equiv 1\pmod{7}$ if $\gcd(x,7)=1$, then $x^3\equiv \pm 1\pmod{7}$ if $\gcd(x,7)=1$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: This equation has no solution in positive integers.

Comment: I don't follow your argument.  I would say that if *one* of $a,b,$ or $c$ is divisible by $7$ then $a^3\equiv b^3$ or $b^3\equiv c^3$ or $c^3\equiv a^3\pmod7$

Comment: Am I missing something? Isnt this a special case of Fermats last theorem, proven by Wildes, no diophantine solutions exist.  Or is it too early in the morning for me to be doing math?

Answer (score 1):

If none of a,b,c are divisible by 7,
then each of a$^3$, b$^3$ and c$^3$ = either 1 or -1 (mod 7).
A contradiction ensues.

Comment: How to get contradiction

Comment: Check all 8 possibilities. @MuhammadShanu

Answer (score 1):

For any integer $x$ we have $x^3 \equiv -1 \text{ or } 0 \text{ or }1\pmod{7}$. 
$a^3+b^3=c^3$

$a^3+b^3+(-c)^3=0 \equiv 0\pmod{7}$ [Take modulo 7 on the whole equaton]

This sum can be zero iff one of them is $-1 \bmod7$, one is $1 \bmod 7$ and one is $0 \bmod 7$. Or if each one of them is $0 \bmod 7$.

The result follows.

Answer (score 0):

There's 36 combinations of $a$ and $b$ in the integers mod 7, where they're not already $0$. Just try checking them.

Answer (score 0):

$7$ is prime. This implies that the multiplicative group $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$ is cyclic and of order $6$. It follows that the image of the action $x\mapsto x^3$ is a subgroup of order $6/3=2$. So there are only two values for $x^3$ mod $7$.

(Plus a third value, $0$, since $0$ was excluded from $\mathbb{Z}_7^*$. But we are assuming none of the three variables are $0$ mod $7$.)

It's easy to see those values are $1$ and $-1\equiv6$. Now, can you solve this equation mod $7$: $$A+B\equiv C$$ using only the values $1$ and $-1$?

In general, this fact about how powers of integers mod $p$ can sometimes only take certain values can be useful. For example, consider $a^5+b^5=c^5$ and look at $11$ in place of $7$. It's the same situation, since $5$ divides $11-1$.

Or consider $a^4+b^4=c^{12}+7$ If you look at that one mod $13$, the $12$th power can only be $0$ or $1$. But the $4$th powers are so restricted that they cannot sum to $7$ or $8$.